# Botão de Login do Facebook não tem nenhuma ação

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk, api

Estou testando a API de Login do Facebook, porém ao clicar no botão **Entrar com o Facebook** nada acontece, apenas a barra onde possui a hora fica preta durante um momento e depois volta com a cor da aplicação definido no arquivo `styles.xml`. Não passa nem mesmo em nenhum dos três eventos do atributo `facebookCallBack`, `onSuccess()`, `onError()` e `onCancel()`.

**MainActivity.class**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

**MainActivityFragment.class**:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView description;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    FacebookCallback<LoginResult> facebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if (profile != null){
                description.setText("Bem-vindo, " + profile.getFirstName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Cancelado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Erro!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, facebookCallback);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.giancarloandroid.loginauthenticationexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Não aparece nada no LogCat? Como está as configurações n painel do developer Facebook? Gerou a hash direito?

Comment: Não aparece nada. Gerei sim, porém estava usandocochash errado e coloquei um código em desenvolvimento que mostrava qual o hash que estava jogando para a API do Facebook e troquei o hash anterior por esse que mostrou no logcat com o código em desenvolvimento.

Comment: Tenta adicionar junto a permissão de email o public_profile

Comment: Mesmo adicionando essa permissão não teve resultado

Comment: O keyhash está correto lá no painel do desenvolvedor no Facebook? Porque se tiver incorreta, ele não abre.

Comment: Está certo, mas tive que gerar via código e ele deve erro de não estivesse certo

Comment: Eu coloquei seu mesmo código aqui no meu projeto e restá funcionando belezinha! Talvez seja a questão do seu  `facbook_app_id `

Comment: Você alterou o manifest conforme manda a documentação?https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android?locale=pt_BR

Comment: Como esta configurado o seu logcat? Verbose? Only Application?

Comment: Não precisaria de um onClickListener para esse "botão"?

Comment: @GiancarloAbelGiulian vc tentou instanciar e implementar a interface do callback do Facebook diretamente no "registerCallback"? Como assim:

loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {...

Answer (score -2):

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).